# Обращение к элементам DOM дерева подгруженных через некоторое время

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Работаю с чатом.
И не могу обратиться к новым подгруженным сообщениям. 
Как  обратиться через jquery к тем элементам которые были подгружены через определенное время после всей загрузки DOM дерева?

Comment: смотря, как Вы их подгружаете. Предоставьте код, пожалуйста

Comment: Вытягиваю данные для сообщения через $.getJSON и передаю своему методу, код метода: http://pastebin.com/984kMbp8

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы пытаетесь обратиться к только что созданным записям по имени класса. Т.е. `.chat-item`, или по id, или как-то так?

Comment: да, после добавления их в DOM мне нужно к ним обратиться, но этого у меня не получается сделать

Comment: вызвали `$("#messages").append(element)` и после этого хотите получить доступ к добавленным тегам и это не получается?

Comment: ну вот как-то так http://pastebin.com/VuvHjeMy может через onclick в html и будет работать? я не знаю, я просто не могу передать параметр в метод через onclick в html

Comment: Забыл заметить, что если обновить страницу, то всё что выведено через php прекрасно работает так, как загружено DOM дерево до подключения js файла. Это к сведении, что бы вы знали что оно всё же работает в определенной ситуации. Не судите за слова, просто дополнил информации. Спасибо

Comment: где `class="chat-moder-block"` и `id="del_mess"`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3GYHP6tU вот полный html который должен быть, те элементы про которые вы спрашивали подгружаются в переменную element на  18 строке `element += data.moder_panel`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не дублируйте id DOM элементов.
2. Используйте делегирование событий родителем для элементов, которые появляются позднее.

   ```
   <span class="chat-moder-block">
     <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-1 edit_mess" title="Редактировать сообщение"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-times fa-1 del_mess" title="Удалить сообщение"></i>
   </span>

   $("#messages").on("click", ".del_mess", function() {
     chat.del($(this).closest('.chat-item').data('id'));
     return false;
   });
   ```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за хороший совет, помогло.

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан - Владислав, обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответа. Если Вы хотите, чтобы Вам продолжали отвечать в будущем, отмечайте ответ, который Вы считаете правильным, щелчком по этотому знаку.

Comment: Я сразу после ответа щелкнул, но у меня рейтинг еще низкий, как станет больше оно должно само добавить, ну или же я вернусь и добавлю сам!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы события срабатывали на элементы, которые подгружаются динамически, нужно использовать функцию on.
Пример:

```
$('#static_element').on('click','.dynamic_element', function(){
  $(this).hide(); 
});
```

То есть у нас должен быть элемент обертка, который будет досутпен сразу при загрузке и в который будут подгружаться динамические элементы. Далее в функцию on вторым параметром мы передаем селектор для динамических элементов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения